# jQuery('select') error in Joomla 3.3 administator

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools

I'm running a Joomla! 3.3.0 installation and the front-end is fine, however I'm getting a *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function* in the back end that is really annoying.

When the error occurs, the "Search Tools" button doesn't work and I can't search a keyword, and the article/module edit page doesn't display any tabs.

**This is really strange behavior since the error can disappear if I refresh the page a few times.**

I realise this is most probably a Mootools/jQuery conflict, but in theory everything is the way it should be regarding noConflict being enabled.

Here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function -> index.php?option=com_content&view=articles:206
```

The lines where the error is displayed:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
                    jQuery('select').chosen({"disable_search_threshold":10,"allow_single_deselect":true,"placeholder_text_multiple":"Selecione alguma op\u00e7\u00e3o","placeholder_text_single":"Selecione uma op\u00e7\u00e3o","no_results_text":"Sem resultados correspondentes"});
                });
```

I'm using Isis template whit no modifications
 for the administrator and this is how the .js files are being called in the `head`:

```
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.ui.sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/tabs-state.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" async="async"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.searchtools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/html5fallback.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="templates/isis/js/template.js?7069fd2c34fe5425e23362e429f9e94a" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="plugins/content/mgthumbnails/shadowbox/shadowbox.js" type="text/javascript">     </script>
```

I already tried plugins [Mootools Enabler/Disabler](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fextensions.joomla.org%2Fextensions%2Fcore-enhancements%2Fperformance%2Fmootools%2F22236&ei=CzTyU8mHDYvesASq8ICgCA&usg=AFQjCNExMphbWiEenbfJq6JBiz8YZK0Ypg&sig2=ASCxk-nhglNXnSZ8Ak6-Cg&bvm=bv.73231344,d.cWc) and [jQuery Easy](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fextensions.joomla.org%2Fextensions%2Fcore-enhancements%2Fperformance%2Fjquery-scripts%2F18327&ei=KDTyU_6AEuLLsQTMy4K4CQ&usg=AFQjCNGQSv_SNnp7naicn1FVBaTt14zh0w&sig2=0EpjOWD7_kTvO8ehkkrZoA&bvm=bv.73231344,d.cWc) with no luck, all they do is to break both front and back-end if I disable mootools or mootools-more.

Comment: That error usually means you are calling a function on a var that doesn't exist. Have you tried loading Mootools first with dollar safe mode? (http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was a conflict with the plugin **[Javascript Async & Defer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/25755mZ_FA5A&bvm=bv.74115972,d.eXY)**.

With it disabled the problem is gone.